# Implementar CustomException

Tags: c#

Tengo una clase mensajería, en la cual valido si algún campo requerido esta vacío o reglas de negocio la cual esa información por una variable string llega a la presentación.

```
public class Mensajeria
{
    Resto de código
}
```

Mi pregunta es implementando CustomException puedo hacer lo mismo y si la respuesta es si como llegaría el mensaje hasta la capa de presentación teniendo que pasar por la capa de ServicioAplicación.

Comment: Ha prueba ErrorProvider?

Comment: Hola Pedro, puedes incluir en tu pregunta el código que tienes hasta el momento? o detallar mejor cual es el problema exacto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si vas aplicar validaciones de regla de negocio usa un framework que te ayude como ser

[FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation)

Entonces podrias aplicar reglas de validaciones indicando que campos puedes estar vaciones.

Al ejecutar las validaciones obtendras la lista de errores. No inventes la rueda ya existen librerias que permiten aplicar validaciones en las entidades de negocio.

Defines las reglas de validacion

```
public class CustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer> {
   public CustomerValidator() {
     RuleFor(customer => customer.Surname).NotNull();
   }
}
```

ejecutas la validaciones

```
Customer customer = new Customer(); //esta entidad vendria desde la presentacion
CustomerValidator validator = new CustomerValidator();
ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(customer);
```

y por ultimo tomas los mensajes de error si es que se produce alguno

```
if(! results.IsValid) {
   foreach(var failure in results.Errors) {
     Console.WriteLine("Property " + failure.PropertyName + " failed validation. Error was: " + failure.ErrorMessage);
   }
 }
```

Despues puedes devolver la lista de mensajes o podrias retornar un Exception que contenga los string de estos mensajes.
Recomendaria que devuelveas un exceltion, es mas este framework lo soporta si usas

```
 validator.ValidateAndThrow(customer);
```

desde le UI simplemente capturas el exception con un try..catch

Comment: FluentValidation lo instalo en mi capa de ServiciosDominio? y mi entidad de negocio tiene que heredar de AbstractValidator y crear un constructor en la entidad de negocio donde dentro de ese constructor valido?

Comment: claro va en la capa de negocio. No hereda de nada, es una clase separada donde define las reglas. Revisa un poco la documentacion de la libreria para analizar los ejemplos de como lo utiliza, yo puse algo muy basico

Comment: Ok, Leandro gracias.

Comment: Cuando capture la exception con un try catch puedo mostrar esos mensajes en un MessageBox.

Comment: claro por supuesto, cuando capturas el exception estas en la UI puedes mostrarlo como mas guste

Comment: Leandro, llegue a imnplementarlo y me fuciona de maravilla, excelente recomendación.